# Understanding the abbreviated labels on a Japanese driving license

Tags: translation, kanji, readings, abbreviations

I'm attempting to write a guide to understanding what is written on a Japanese Driving License for [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_license_in_Japan#Driving_License_Card), but I've reached the limit of my reading comprehension abilities.

Here's a labelled image of the sample license that is used by the National Police Agency in public information literature:

[image]

I'm struggling with the abbreviated labels in the left-hand margin for sections 10, 11 and 12, and the list of abbreviated vehicle categories in section 13.

Here is my best effort at translation. Would anyone be kind enough to correct and complete them? It could well be that I've got some of these translations wrong: in particular, I think there might be something about automatic / manual transmission in there.

Next to section 10: 二・小・原
*Date of issue of first small motorcycle license*

Next to section 11: 他
*Date of issue of first non-motorcycle license*

Next to section 12: 二種
*Date of issue of first motorcycle license*

First row of section 13, left-to-right:

- 大型 Large vehicle
- 中型 Medium vehicle
- 普通 Ordinary vehicle
- 大特 Large special vehicle
- 大自二 Large motorcycle
- 普自二 Ordinary motorcycle
- 小特 Small special vehicle

Second row of section 13, left-to-right:

- 原付 Moped
- け引 Trailer
- 大二 Large commercial passenger-carrying vehicle
- 中二 Medium commercial passenger-carrying vehicle
- 普二 Ordinary commercial passenger-carrying vehicle
- 大特二 ???
- け引二 ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 10 - "二・小・原" is "二輪・小型特殊・原付". So it means "motrocycle/small spacial veicle/moped".

Section 11 - "他" is anything except "二輪・小型特殊・原付". So it means "大型・中型・普通・大型特殊・けん引".

Section 12 - "二種" is "Class 2". It's "commercial passenger-carrying vehicle".

Section 13 first row

- 大型 - Large vehicle (e.g. dump truck)
- 中型 - Medium vehicle (e.g. truck)
- 普通 - Ordinary vehicle (e.g. car)
- 大特（大型特殊） - Large special vehicle (e.g. crane truck/shovel truck/road roller)
- 大自二（大型自動二輪） - Large motorcycle (i.e. motorcycle over 400cc)
- 普自二（普通自動二輪） - Ordinary motorcycle (i.e. motorcycle under 400cc)
- 小特（小型特殊） - Small special vehicle (e.g. small tractor)

Section 13 second row

- 原付（原動機付自転車） - Moped (i.e. motorcycle under 50cc)
- け引（けん引） - Trailer
- 大二（大型二種） - Large commercial passenger-carrying vehicle (e.g. large bus)
- 中二（中型二種） - Medium commercial passenger-carrying vehicle (e.g. small bus)
- 普二（普通二種） - Ordinary commercial passenger-carrying vehicle (e.g. taxi)
- 大特二（大型特殊二種） - Large commercial passenger-carrying special vehicle
- け引二（けん引二種） - Commercial passenger-carrying trailer

> I think there might be something about automatic / manual transmission in there.

"Restricted to automatic" is written like [this](http://img5.blogs.yahoo.co.jp/ybi/1/bf/b6/enakoukyobaka/folder/447320/img_447320_9636427_1?1344869990) in the section 6.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I never heard of a "passenger carrying trailer..."

Comment: @Pitarou It's for [tandem busses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulated_bus) or [trailer busses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailer_bus).

Answer (score 1):

I've received the answer elsewhere from someone I believe to be an expert. He made the following amendments:

- The label for section 10 is *motorcyle*, not *small motorcyle*
- The label for section 12 is *instructor's license*, not *heavy motorcycle license*
- The last five vehicle categories (大二、中二、普二、大特二、け引二) are for instructors licenses.

Here's how the amended translation looks:

> Next to section 10: 二・小・原 Date of issue of first motorcycle license
>
> Next to section 11: 他 Date of issue of first non-motorcycle license
>
> Next to section 12: 二種 Date of issue of first driving instructor license
>
> First row of section 13, left-to-right:
>
> - 大型 Large vehicle
> - 中型 Medium vehicle
> - 普通 Ordinary vehicle
> - 大特 Large special vehicle
> - 大自二 Large motorcycle
> - 普自二 Ordinary motorcycle
> - 小特 Small special vehicle
>
> Second row of section 13, left-to-right:
>
> - 原付 Moped
> - け引 Trailer
> - 大二 Driving instructor: heavy vehicle
> - 中二 Driving instructor: medium vehicle
> - 普二 Driving instructor: ordinary vehicle
> - 大特二 Driving instructor: special heavy vehicle
> - け引二 Driving instructor: trailer

Comment: The 二種 licenses are not for driving instructors. They are for passenger vehicles like buses and taxis. See here http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E7%A8%AE%E9%81%8B%E8%BB%A2%E5%85%8D%E8%A8%B1

Comment: Wiki(英語版)が間違えてるんだわ。http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_license_in_Japan#12._Date_of_issue_of_first_driving_instructor_license_.28.E4.BA.8C.E7.A8.AE.29_.28note_on_dates.29